# ToString and EqualsAndHashCode annotations in spring java

Tags: java, spring, annotations, lombok

I see ToString and EqualsAndHashCode annotations getting used above many classes. When de we use them? What unique functionality do they provide?

Comment: these annotations are from project lombok jar. https://projectlombok.org/. Go through official documentation on its purpose

Answer (score 1):

They will generate a default implementation of the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` method during compilation, based on the fields.

Lombok generates them for you, so you don't need to have them in your source code. And that also means that if you add a field later, you cannot forget to add it to all the methods mentioned above.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Answer (score -1):

The annotation are probably because how closely Java Object's [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) are tied together. They are one of the fundamental contracts in Java which needs to be adhered by the objects in Java.